# How to use autoprefixer for external css files - webpack

Tags: css, web, build, webpack, autoprefixer

I have all the css files inside `${ROOT}/resource/css/`. While building using webpack, I want to copy all the css files to `${ROOT}/build/css/` with desired vendor prefixes added to all the css rules.
Currently I am using [copywebpackplugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy all the css files as is to `${ROOT}/build/css/`. I am struggling to add add a step to add vender prefixes. Please help.

Below the my webpack config:

```
config = {
    entry: {
        "new": "./resources/js/new",
        "view": "./resources/js/view",
        "edit": "./resources/js/edit",
        "preview": "./resources/js/preview",
        "sidebar": "./resources/js/sidebar",
        "frame": "./resources/js/frame"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: "build/js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loaders: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: './resources/css/*.css',
            to: './build/css/[name].css'
        }])
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you installed autoprefixer? Show us the configuration file

Comment: It is recommended to use postcss loader in the configuration https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader

Comment: @hunzaboy, added webpack configuration

Comment: you just need to add the postcss loader. check the link i added in my previous comment. It should solve the problem.

Comment: As far as I understand, postcss loader is for loading css. This will be helpful if I load css in some js file, something like require('style.css'). In my scenario, I am linking css files from HTML files. I am not loading anywhere. That's why I am copying the entire css directory to build directory. I just want that the copied files should have vender prefixes added. Can postcss loader help in achieving this?

Comment: I can use gulp to achieve same. But to keep things simple, I wish I could do this using webpack.

Comment: Yes postcss will do this. You need to configure it properly. Here are the steps https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#webpack-1

Comment: @hunzaboy, Not working as expected. Files are getting copied as is. No vender prefixes are added. going wrong somewhere. Can you attach the sample config?